# Mini cart is not refreshing when user switch the store from one store to another Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have added a product from Store A and mini cart showing the correct number of items, then I have switched to Store B mini cart is empty. But when I go to https://www.valleyspice.com/checkout/cart and refresh this page, the mini cart is not empty. I am using Magento 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Magento manages quote store wise. So ideally, if you add the product in store A, then it will not reflect in store B. Another thing is that product should also be assigned to both stores.

Comment: But when I go to https://www.valleyspice.com/checkout/cart and refresh this page I can see the products from both the stores